# I am trying to add two tables in the middle of document

Tags: tables

The first table is fine (as I have added it to page 2) and table 2 and 3, I want to add them at about page 5. Its the same code for them too but they are displaying at the end of document and with a gap. 
I have used [t] for the top of the page.
I have shifted the code even at the start of the document, still showing up at the end.
Works well for the 1st table not for the second.

Code:

```
\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
\caption{Directed Graph}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
Name&Nodes&Edges&k=1(time)&k=1($\%$ ratio)&k=10(time)&k=10($\%$ ratio)&k=100(time)&k=100($\%$ ratio)\\ \hline

Core-Citation& 23166& 91500&0.701 &0.0103 &1.035 &0.017 &2.300 &0.0327  \\ \hline

HEP-TH & 27710 & 352807 &4.355 &0.0231 &8.0834 &0.04655 &12.833&0.0747  \\ \hline

Slashdot& 82168& 948464&1.927 &0.0001 &9.586 &0.0071 &54.232 &0.0449  \\ \hline

Web-Stanford& 281903 &2312497 & 973.69& 0.065&1631.48 &0.106 &2013.64 &0.106  \\ \hline


Youtube Links&1138499 &4942297 &200.23 &0.0014 &583.22 &0.0050 &1034.674 & 0.00811\\

\hline\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{Un-Directed Graph}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
Name&Nodes&Edges&k=1(time)&k=1($\%$ ratio)&k=10(time)&k=10($\%$ ratio)&k=100(time)&k=100($\%$ ratio)\\ \hline

COND-MAT&23133 &93497 &0.6701 &0.0024 &1.541 &0.0109 &5.618 &0.0591 \\ \hline

Email-Enron&36692 &183831 &0.423 &0.0010 &0.743 &0.0028 &4.6102 &0.0238 \\ \hline

Brightkite&58228 &214078 &10.1704 &0.024 &10.145 &10.170 &13.202 &0.0291 \\ \hline

Amazon(MDS)&334863 &925872 &2.968 &0.0000831 &3.190 &0.0000855 &3.711 &0.0000978 \\ \hline


Hyves&1402673 &2777419 &3119.21 &0.0132 & 4229.20 & 0.0136& 4772.69 &0.01490 \\

\hline\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: These tables are wider than a normal page width. So how are you making them visible? Moreover, float placement depends on other features of the document. So I think you are not giving enough information. Please make a complete minimal document that shows the problem.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! You will need to show us more of the document.

Comment: And please read http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020 about the things that influence placement of floats.

Comment: By the way, are there also figures in the document?

Comment: the main effect of `[t]` on your first table is to prevent the table being placed on a float page so makes it much more likely that both tables go to the end.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why are you using `table*` environments rather than the more common `table` environments? Is it because you have a two-column document and want the tables to span both columns?

Comment: There are no figures in the document. And yes, I am using 2 column document. As the table is wide, so want to span both columns. The table contains mostly numbers, so they can easily visible. The main hurdle is how to move them in between the document.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest that you place both `tabular` environments and their associated `\caption` statements in a single `table` environment. I would also like to encourage you that you (a) provide more structure to the table headers and (b) give the tables a more "open" look by getting rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{Directed Graph}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrr*{6}{c}@{}} 
\toprule
Name&Nodes&Edges&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$k=1$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$k=10$} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{$k=100$} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9} 
&&& time & \% ratio & time & \% ratio & time & \% ratio \\ 
\midrule
Core-Citation& 23166& 91500&0.701 &0.0103 &1.035 &0.017 &2.300 &0.0327  \\     
HEP-TH & 27710 & 352807 &4.355 &0.0231 &8.0834 &0.04655 &12.833&0.0747  \\     
Slashdot& 82168& 948464&1.927 &0.0001 &9.586 &0.0071 &54.232 &0.0449  \\     
Web-Stanford& 281903 &2312497 & 973.69& 0.065&1631.48 &0.106 &2013.64 &0.106  \\        
Youtube Links&1138499 &4942297 &200.23 &0.0014 &583.22 &0.0050 &1034.674 & 0.00811\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\bigskip  % some vertical whitespace between the tabulars

\caption{Un-Directed Graph}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrr*{6}{c}@{}} 
\toprule
Name&Nodes&Edges&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$k=1$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$k=10$} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{$k=100$} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9} 
&&& time & \% ratio & time & \% ratio & time & \% ratio \\ 
\midrule
COND-MAT&23133 &93497 &0.6701 &0.0024 &1.541 &0.0109 &5.618 &0.0591 \\   
Email-Enron&36692 &183831 &0.423 &0.0010 &0.743 &0.0028 &4.6102 &0.0238 \\     
Brightkite&58228 &214078 &10.1704 &0.024 &10.145 &10.170 &13.202 &0.0291 \\    
Amazon(MDS)&334863 &925872 &2.968 &0.0000831 &3.190 &0.0000855 &3.711 &0.0000978 \\  
Hyves&1402673 &2777419 &3119.21 &0.0132 & 4229.20 & 0.0136& 4772.69 &0.01490 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, and do omit the `[t]` position preference specifier. I trust you've understood David Carlisle's comment on this subject.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and making it more clear than before. But still they are at the end. Even I have removed [t] from all the tables, tried separately for the second table but still at the mid of last page.

Comment: @RashidAzizRaja - In that case, please edit your original posting to provide some sorely needed additional information about your document: Which document class do you use? How wide and tall is the text block? Are there any floats that precede the two tabulars? Absent this information, your posting will iikely be closed as being too unclear to be answerable.